# Cisco Extended ACL Protocols and Ports?

Tags: cisco, firewall

My question is about the tcp/udp port numbers on an extended ACL on a Cisco firewall. I want to allow udp and tcp to a server that uses https.

My commands so far are:

`access-list Ex extended permit tcp <ip> <subnet> <ip> <subnet> eq 443 
access-list Ex extended permit udp <ip> <subnet> <ip> <subnet> eq 80`

Should I also have `access-list Ex extended permit tcp <ip> <subnet> <ip> <subnet> eq 80` and `access-list Ex extended permit udp <ip> <subnet> <ip> <subnet> eq 443`?

Comment: HTTP and HTTPS use TCP, not UDP.

Answer (score 2):

no need to open UDP you need to open only TCP ports 80 and 443

```
access-list Ex extended permit tcp <ip> <subnet> <ip> <subnet> eq 443 
access-list Ex extended permit tcp <ip> <subnet> <ip> <subnet> eq 80
```